# Sending a value from html to controller in angularjs. Issue with scope?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive

I have have a web app set up to display charts using the highcharts-ng directive.

I have the same type of chart with the same series data displaying on multiple views. The only difference between the charts is the height value which I would like to be able to set when I initialise my chart in my html markup.

This is how I have set things up:

The highcharts-ng directive is installed through bower.

I initialise my chart as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="AgeChartController" >
    <highchart diagramHeight="500" id="{{link + '_chart'}}" config="ageChartConfig">
</highchart></div>
```

In my AgeChartController I do the following:

- Pull data from JSON file
- Get chart height attribute from diagramHeight
- Construct Highcharts options object and send diagramHeight to this options object

  ```
  angular.module('socialDashboard')    
  .controller('AgeChartController', function ($scope, $http, $attrs) {

  var seventeenCount = 0;
  var eighteenCount = 0;
  var twentyFiveCount = 0;
  var thirtyFiveCount = 0;
  var chartHeight = 0;
  var posts = [];

  $http.get('dummy_content.json')
  .then(function(res){
  posts = res.data;

  for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    if (posts[i].age <= 17) {
      seventeenCount++;
    }
    else if ((posts[i].age >= 18) && (posts[i].age <= 24)) {
      eighteenCount++;
    }
    else if ((posts[i].age >= 25) && (posts[i].age <= 34)) {
      twentyFiveCount++;
    }
    else if (posts[i].age >= 35) {
      thirtyFiveCount++;
    }
  }

  chartHeight = $attrs.diagramHeight;

  $scope.ageChartConfig = {
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: chartHeight,
        backgroundColor: false
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['< 17', '18 - 24', '25 - 34', '> 35']
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Post count'
      },
      labels:
      {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      floating: true,
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 60,
      x: -60
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function () {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
          this.x + ': ' + this.y;
      }
    },
    navigation: {
      buttonOptions: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Post count',
      showInLegend: false,
      data: [{
        color: '#9365b8',
        y: seventeenCount
      }, {
        color: '#2c82c9',
        y: eighteenCount
      }, {
        color: '#41a85f',
        y: twentyFiveCount
      }, {
        color: '#fac51c',
        y: thirtyFiveCount
      }]
    }],
    loading: false
  };

  });

  });
  ```

However when I declare my chart elsewhere with diagramHeight set to 200:

```
<div ng-controller="AgeChartController">
    <highchart diagramHeight="200" id="{{link + '_chart'}}" config="ageChartConfig">
</highchart></div>
```

Only one of the two values get pulled and my chart is set the same across all charts (height 500). Why is this? Does this have something to do with my scope? I'm pretty new to angular and still getting my head around scope.

Comment: you must set options for each chart in directive not in controller, You can extend default options from controller. Don't assing options to the scope in controller, because it will effect all the child directvies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use angular factory to configure chart

```
app.factory('chartname', function () {
    var agechart={   // your all chart option here
        .
        .
   }
   return agechart;
});
```

You can use above factory in any controller now just like

```
app.controller("controllername",function(chartname){
   $scope.ageChartConfig=chartname;
});
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to set up a factory for every chart? The things is I use the same chart twice with the only difference being chart height. I would like to be able to push this variation in hight to my chart options object but am unsure how to do this

Comment: Are you using both chart on same page ?

Comment: No they are set up on different views

Comment: You have to  duplicate chart object to use height chart2=chartname  then change height in second cahrt like chart2.options.chart.height=chartheight;

Comment: Really? That's a pity as this adds a lot of duplicate code. I was able to pass in a height value into my options object when I was just using jquery. Surely there must be some way of doing it here.

Comment: Not all code just object chart2=chartname then change height in second cahrt like chart2.options.chart.height=chartheight;

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! This works and I now understand Angularjs just a little bit better.